# Communicate with apple airplay

Tags: android, stream, airplay

i'm a mobile developer and i want to know is there any way to cast music to this service with an android device?
i'm already using shairport-sync library as my server. and i want to send Musics to server but i can't find any source code or example code to how to do that.
Shairport sync library:
https://github.com/mikebrady/shairport-sync

```
import nothing
while true:
    print(":D")
```

Comment: I can tell you that it is possible; I have the doubleTwist app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.doubleTwist.androidPlayer) on my Android phone and it streams to AirPlay devices. I don't know how that is being done, but I'm guessing it is difficult because there aren't many apps that do it well.